# How to change post request to get redirect with minimum code changes in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, https, post-redirect-get

My struts version is 2.3.15.3

In my current struts2 project, all post requests do not redirect to get requests

So I will get resubmit alert when I click the back button if I use https and chrome

How to use minimum effort to change them to keep using post request, but use get redirect to show the JSP? Can I just modify the `struts.xml`?

Or, is it possible to prevent the alert without PRG?

this is my current code

---

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="Get" class="test.PostAction">
    <result name="gotoform">/WEB-INF/jsp/PostForm.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/showGet.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**`PostAction.java`:**

```
public class PostAction  extends ActionSupport{
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Map para = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
        if(para.get("post")==null)
        {
            return "gotoform";
        }
        else
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }
}
```

**`PostForm.jsp`:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Get.action" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="post" value="yes">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`showGet.jsp`:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display here</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**New `showGet.jsp`:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display here, Post value=</h1> <%= request.getParameter("post") %>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**new `PostAction.java`:**

```
package test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;


public class PostAction  extends ActionSupport{

    private String post;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Map para = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();

        System.out.print("post = "+post);
        if(para.get("post")==null)
        {
            return "gotoform";
        }
        else
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }

    public String getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(String post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

**new 2 `showGet.jsp`:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display here</h1>,
        <s:property value="post"/>,
        ${post},
        <%= post %>,
        <%= getPost() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional action required to expose `redirectAction` result.

```xml
<action name="showGet">
  <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/showGet.jsp</result> 
</action>

<action name="Get" class="test.PostAction">
    <result name="gotoform">/WEB-INF/jsp/PostForm.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">showGet</result>
</action>
```

Comment: This is works, but how about if I need the post data in jsp? Please see the New showGet.jsp. How can I get the post value?

Comment: Create a property named `post` in the action class with a setter to comply the JavaBeans spec. It should be of type string, and when you submit a form this property should be set.

Comment: I added post property but it cannot display on jsp, for the `System.out.print("post = "+post);` , I can see the console output is `INFO:   post = null
INFO:   post = yes`, the action is called two time, at the second time, the value is set to post, at jsp, I tried `<s:property value="post"/>,
        ${post},` but the value is not displayed

Comment: I just did another trial, if I change back to not redirect, I can use `${post}` to show the value, but I don't know how to get the value if I use redirect

Comment: To show the value `post` you need to map a method for `showGet` action, where you an initialize the property before you return SUCCESS result.

Comment: Now I found the problem, I added the action class to the redirect target, then I can get the value